# Why does my structures fail to create a rectangle in C?

Tags: c, struct

I was given this simple task:

1. A "rectangle" structure must be defined by 2 points - the edges of the diagonal.
   The following functions must be set:
   A. Rectangle input.
   B. A function that receives a rectangle and returns its area.
   C. A function that receives a rectangle and a dot. The function returns TRUE in case the point is found Inside the rectangle, otherwise it returns FALSE.

and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

// ex1
typedef struct{
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;

typedef struct{
    Point a;
    Point b;
} Rect;

void ex1_1(Rect rect1);
double ex1_2(Rect rect1);
int ex1_3(Rect rect1, Point a);

int main()
{
    Rect r;
    Point p1 = {2, 2}, p2 = {10, 10};
    ex1_1(r);
    printf("%lf\n", ex1_2(r));
    printf("%d\n", ex1_3(r, p1));
    printf("%d\n", ex1_3(r, p2));
    return 0;
}

void ex1_1(Rect rect1)
{
    Point p1, p2;
    printf("Enter the bottom left edge (x y): ");
    scanf_s("%lf%lf", &p1.x, &p1.y);
    printf("Enter the top right edge (x y): ");
    scanf_s("%lf%lf", &p2.x, &p2.y);
    rect1.a = p1; rect1.b = p2;
}

double ex1_2(Rect rect1)
{
    return (rect1.b.x - rect1.a.x) *
           (rect1.b.y - rect1.a.y);

}

int ex1_3(Rect rect1, Point p)
{
    return rect1.a.x < p.x && p.x < rect1.b.x &&
           rect1.a.y < p.y && p.y < rect1.b.y;
}
```

However, when I run my program is prints me only zeroes, why is that?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and show a complete example. What do you mean by "fails to create a rectangle"? Why should you see anything other than zeros? How do you run the program, what should the output be, and why? You should show hard-coded input.

Comment: Unrelated: Use meaningful function names, i.e. names that tells/hints what the function is doing. Names like ex1_1, ex1_2 are confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an uninitialized variable to the `ex_1_1` function, this is undefined behaviour. Also, passing a copy of the variable to the function doesn't alter the contents of `r` inside `main`.

Pass a pointer:

```
void ex1_1(Rect *rect1);

int main()
{
    Rect r;
    Point p1 = {2, 2}, p2 = {10, 10};
    ex1_1(&r);
    ...
}

void ex1_1(Rect *rect1)
{
    Point p1, p2;
    printf("Enter the bottom left edge (x y): ");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &p1.x, &p1.y);
    printf("Enter the top right edge (x y): ");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &p2.x, &p2.y);
    rect1->a = p1; rect1->b = p2;
}
```

Comment: Passing a pointer is the correct solution, but your explanation is muddled. The problem is that a *copy of* the local variable is passed when calling the function; the purpose of the function is to initialize what was passed to it, but modifying the copy doesn't modify the original. While it may undefined behaviour to use `r` *since* `ex1_1` has failed to initialize it, the concept of undefined behaviour does not help explain *why* `ex1_1` failed to initialize it.

Comment: And thats what I said:  _in consequence r remains untouched_ ;)

Comment: Yes, and what I am saying is that it is incorrect to say "in consequence" there. It's not because the variable was uninitialized *when it was passed to the function*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel totally right, edited!